# Excel - Delete duplicate data in separate rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with multiple columns. The first is the master and the 4 or 5 others contain data that I would like to eliminate from the master.  How would I perform this function?

ie:

```
   Column 1       Column 2       Column 3
---------------|-------------|--------------|
               |             |              |
test 1         | test 2      | test 2       | 
test 2         | test 4      | test 1       |
test 3         |             |              |
test 4         |             |              |
test 5         |             |              |
```

I would like to remove test 1,2 & 4 from column 1 because they were found in Column (n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it should be done manually. Suppose your table starts in `A1` and has no headers.

Then I would:

1. Add an artificial column (for example `D`) with formula. For `D1` it will be `=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$5;A1)+COUNTIF($C$1:$C$5;A1)`, fill down other cells in the column.
2. Add filter to the table via `Home -> Editing -> Sort & Filter -> Filter`. Dropdown buttons will appear on column top cells.
3. Switch off all values except `0` from artificial column using dropdown button (apply filter).

How it works: every `COUNTIF` finds the count of occurrences of values from `A` column in values in either `B` or `C` columns. If value from `A` is in `B` or `C` the `COUNTIF` returns non `0` value. So we just have to exclude these non `0` values.

Comment: I don't understand your answer ... at all.  I don't even know what to say to get you to clarify.  Ok, I'll try...  1) What is an artificial column? 2) What is and why am I adding a filter?  3) "switch of 0 values from artificial column" ... huh? 4) "If it should be done manually" ... huh?  5) "using vlookup" ... huh/how?

Comment: Do you implement the task using macro or just manually? Do you have a predefined number of columns?

Comment: yes, predefined columns.

Comment: basically just want a filter applied to column 1 that checks if the value exists in other columns and then deletes it from column 1 if found ...

Comment: Deletion is required or hiding is enough?

Comment: If I can copy/paste only the visible columns then hiding will be enough ...

Comment: I edited the answer. Hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21160/discussion-between-nidu-and-james-huckabone)

Comment: nidu, you're formula could be shortened to `=COUNTIF($B$1:$C$5,A1)`. Chaage C to the rightmost column with data.